# How to assign keyboard shortcuts in Kontact?

Tags: kde, kubuntu, kmail

I have trouble assigning shortcut in Kontact. Suppose I assign any shortcut in one of the software in kontact (kmail/korganiser etc) then when I open the kontact the shortcut works.

If however I open kontact assign the shortcut there, it will not work when I start kontact again (or the software alone).

This is a problem only for the shortcut which allows to switch from on software to another since those are the only one I cannot assign on each software independently.

So I have two questions:

1. Am I the only one with those problem?
2. Does anyone knows in which file the standard shortcut of contact are written, so I can just change them there? I notice that when I change a shortcut it appears in .kde/share/apps/kontact/kontactui.rc  but when I open kontact again it doesn't work anymore.

I'm using Kubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 2):

1. I have it too. This is a bug. Please report it to KDE.  Might want to test it with 11.04 as well to see if it's in KDE SC 4.6 too.
2. Part of the bug...Kontact's not reading the config file properly

Comment: The bug is still on Kubuntu 11.04. I will report a bug.